# Why is 1 of my 24 CPUs Pegged at 100%?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance, cpu-usage

I have an HP ProLiant DL380 G7 system using 2 6-core CPUs, with Hyper-threading enabled, for a total of 24 logical CPUs (as seen by Windows).

When running our application, total system CPU utilization is good, but one of the 24 CUPs is pegged at 100%:
[image]

**Edit:** This is the PerfMon data for the System process during this time, and for the Processor with the high utilization:
[image]

Is this normal? If not, is there a way to identify which process(es) are using that logical CPU? Windows PerfMon, ResMon, Task Manager, and Process Explorer have been no help, other than identifying that the CPU is at 100%.

Comment: My guess would be that it's in use because a process is using it.

Comment: You know you can hover over the graph and get a hint telling you what process is taking the most cpu on that processor?!

Comment: I would be suspicious of the 100k interrupt delta. You should post a Process Explorer process list screenshot where we can see what it says for things like System, DPCs, Interrupts.

Comment: @RyanRies; our "application" consists of several .Net WCF services that also WebSphere MQ and some 3rd party monitoring software.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers; I noticed that, but according to the PE help, "Note that the mouse tooltips for a processor graph show the name of the process that consumed the most CPU on the entire system at the associated time, not the process that consumed the most CPU on the particular CPU."

Comment: @PatrickCuff - heh, I never noticed. It seems you are right about the process part. The hint however does show the correct % cpu of the overall most consuming process at that timeinterval so if you hover over your CPU and it's showing 100%, I believe you are still good.

Comment: On an older version of windows I used [RATT](https://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/tools/ratteula.mspx) to figure out which driver consumed CPU time. Not sure if it still works or has any successors.

Comment: It's relatively expensive to move a process from one CPU to another, compared to keeping it scheduled on the same CPU, so if a process is really demanding the CPU then the OS is quite often going to prefer not to move it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, we can see from that screenshot that the CPU that's working so hard is spending all its time in kernel mode. (The red color.)

Running Powershell as administrator, type:

```
Get-Process | Select Name, PrivilegedProcessorTime | `
Sort-Object PrivilegedProcessorTime -Descending
```

The process at the top of the list is the process currently using the most kernel mode CPU time right now.  If that process is *not* "System," then you've just figured out what user mode process is causing this CPU usage. If the process with the highest Privileged Processor Time is System, which I suspect it is, then it's a little more complicated.

Open Process Explorer. Optionally, set up your symbol server. Make sure you are running with full UAC elevation. Right click the System "process" and go to Properties. Then go to the Threads tab. Sort the threads by CPU usage. The thread that's causing all this kernel mode work should be here. If you look at the module listed under Start Address, it should give you a clue as to what the work is related to. If it's NDIS.sys, for instance, that's a network interface driver. If you set up the symbol server, you should see the name of a function within a module (unless the module is non-Microsoft,) else you'll just see a numerical offset from the module's start address.

Alternatively, use Xperf from the Windows Performance Toolkit to profile interrupts, DPCs, etc.

```
xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+DPC+INTERRUPT
```

and stop recording with `xperf -d logfile.etl`

Xperf replaces the old Kernrate tool, and can net you some extremely detailed data.

When a CPU is doing work in kernel mode, it's mostly running interrupt service routines. (ISRs) When an interrupt occurs, user mode work is suspended on that processor, and the CPU runs the ISR registered to that interrupt. If you find your CPU spending an inordinate amount of time on these interrupts, that usually indicates a faulty device driver that needs to be updated.

What bugs me (no pun intended) about this scenario though is that it appears as though whatever kernel thread that is doing this seems to be *affinitized* to that one core.  I wonder why the dispatcher seems to be only scheduling the thread to run on that one seemingly arbitrary core. So I have a feeling that we need to find whoever wrote this device driver and show them how to do threaded DPCs, and not to explicitly set an affinity on kernel threads, etc.

Comment: IIRC, it's quite standard behaviour for an OS to only use a single CPU to handle hardware interrupts...

Comment: @Massimo This might have been the case with old operating systems, but not any more. Every CPU gets its own interrupt descriptor table, and every processor has its own IRQL. If one CPU is stuck at a high IRQL for some reason (i.e. it's already servicing an interrupt,) it can't receive interrupts of same or lower level and so Windows will either give the interrupt to another processor, or just hold on to it until a CPU becomes available. Even timers (an object previously notorious for running only on CPU0) have a processor selection algorithm now.

Comment: But yeah, this can be as simple as running a legacy or poorly-written app that is affinitized poorly, and subsequently makes a lot of syscalls. Interrupts usually need to begin and end on the same CPU from which they were called... but normally even a single-threaded app would get "load-balanced" among the cores as it ran... this one seems to have an odd affinity.

Comment: @RyanRies; I installed the Windows Performance Toolkit on the system and used the Windows Performance Recorder; the xperf command above kept giving errors. The high CPU looks like it's coming from: Process - System; Module - ntoskrnl.exe; Thread - Phase1Initialize; Function - KeZeroPages. It only happens when the app is running, so I think (hope) I have enough to take back to the developers, but I am also interested in any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 23):

Show the "CPU Time" column on the "Details" tab in "Task Manager" and look for a process with a CPU time count that's steadily increasing. That's your wedged process. It should be using around 4.17% CPU constantly.

Comment: This would be about 1000 times easier to do if they let you reset cumulative CPU time!

Answer (score 10):

It seems to be all Kernel time, could be Interrupts, they might only get handled by a single CPU.

Comment: +1 - It sure does look like kernel time, doesn't it.

Comment: Would that appear under the "System" process? The PerfMon data we collected during a test run has 100% CPU for the "System" process.

Comment: Yes, I think that would fall under system (if it's listed at all...)

Comment: Couldn't that also be a driver bug or a piece of bad hardware interacting with a driver with no error recovery? Or maybe software calling into the kernel in a tight loop.

Comment: Yes, it could be a number of things.. but probably not a user process.

Comment: @MichelZ, A user process making a bunch of system calls (which would include any kind of I/O) would look like that.

Answer (score 6):

Look for a process with a constant CPU utilization of ~4% (= 1/24 of total available CPU). That should be the one continuously taking up a single CPU.